# Using multithreading to time out the execution of a block

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, performance

I have a class doing some work that could potentially take very long so I need to implement a timeout. The method in question breaks down in several methods and these break down too. All could potentially be slow, so we need to time them out as well. Checking the time in each of them is just going to pollute the code, so I came out with the following solution:

```
class Runner:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # init...
        self.start = None
        self.timeout = 60  # 1 minute for instance
        self.timedout = False

    def countdown():
        while not self.timedout:
            self.timedout = time.time() - self.start > self.timeout

    def run():
        # stuff
        self.start = time.time()
        t = multithreading.Thread(target=self.countdown)
        t.start()
        # do various things, call the chain of methods...
        t.join()
```

And then we just check for `self.timedout` in the relevant methods.

I know I could have used `multiprocessing` and wrap the whole run block in a process with a timeout but (a) I need to fine tune where exit the methods down the line, I can't just interrupt the process because that could mess up the state and (b) I can't even seem to use `Process` because of some pickle error.

My concern is the `coundown` method: is calling `time.time()` a huge number of times going to affect performance? I am considering sleeping the thread for e.g. 1 second in the while loop. But then again I am not sure how the actual mechanism of sleeping a thread may affect performance. If it only affects the performance of the thread where it's running then I'm good, but if it affects the whole execution it's not ok.

Answer (score 0):

The `join()` function takes in an optional parameter which is the timeout value. You can set a timeout value `t.join(no_of_seconds)` and the process will return if it is done running or if it exceeds the timeout threshold. Use `t.isAlive()` to check if the process is still running, terminate it and set your class timeout field after that.

Comment: As I said I can't wrap the run block in a thread or process with a timeout because that might (probably) mess up the state. I need to exit of several methods (if timed out) in precise places.

Comment: Sorry didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Having the loop in `countdown` running constantly is certainly not desirable. Letting it sleep for longer periods would be a good thing, as this suspends the calling thread and allows cycles it would have used to be assigned to other tasks.
However, I also don't see it being overly detrimental to your overall performance.

Still, I recommend using [`Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) from the `threading` module instead.

> This class represents an action that should be run only after a
>   certain amount of time has passed — a timer. `Timer` is a subclass of
>   `Thread` [...]

[`Timer.cancel()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer.cancel) allows to stop the timer while it is still in wait state (although it can be called afterwards without any effect). That allows for the `run` method to end before the timeout interval has elapsed and for `self.timedout` to stay false when no timeout has occurred.

```
class Runner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timedout = False
        self.timeout_sec = 60

    def _set_timeout(self):
        self.timedout = True

    def run(self):
        timer = Timer(self.timeout_sec, function=self._set_timeout)
        timer.start()
        # do various things, call the chain of methods...
        timer.cancel()
```

It is possible to get rid of the `_set_timeout` method using `lambda`. It seems a bit clumsy, though. Since the body of a lambda must be an expression and `var = True` is a statement, one has to use `setattr` and pass the instance to the lambda:

```
timer = Timer(self.timeout_sec, function=lambda inst: setattr(inst, "timedout", True), args=(self,))
```

Another option would be to make `self.timedout` an [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) and call its [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event.set) method to signal the timeout.

```
self.timedout = Event()
[...]
timer = Timer(self.timeout_sec, function=lambda to: to.set(), args=(self.timedout,))
```

Checking if a timeout event has occurred would then be dona via [`Event.is_set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event.is_set):

```
if self.timedout.is_set():
    [...]
```